# Ruby on Rails: How to use select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form

```
  <% form_for(@xyz) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>


      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>

      <%= f.label :type %> 
    <%= f.select :type, XYZ::ALL_TYPES %>
  <% end %>
```

I added attribute "metric_type" to this form and I want to use it but out of this form.
I have constant in model file
AXY = "axy"
BXY = "bxy"
CXY = "cxy"
ALL_METRICS_TYPE = [AXY,BXY,CXY]

How I can use above as an drop down

**Metrics Type:**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following methodology in general:

1) In your view:

```
<%= your_form_variable.select(: type,  Your_model:: ALL_METRICS_TYPE, {:include_blank => 'Please select'}) %>
```

2) in your model:

```
ALL_METRICS_TYPE = [["value which will passed and stored in db", 'what you want to display in the dropdown'], [...]]
```

EDIT:

To use it outside a form, use the raw select helper described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

```
select("foo", "bar", Your_model:: ALL_METRICS_TYPE, {:include_blank => true})
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this but I have a different case. I need to use <% select %> after the form_for scope, i will say after <% end% >.

Comment: What is foo and bar are here...?

Comment: :) look at the link, they'll create the name of your select html tag

Comment: that's whatever you want, it will be passed in params the way you set it, no other consequence. But if you want rails to behave automatically you should stick to it's conventions: foo = model name, bar = column name